# Agnostisch vs. generisch

Tags: meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen **agnostisch** und **generisch**? Ich möchte ausdrücken, dass der Software-Kern für unterschiedliche Anwendungsfälle immer derselbe ist und folglich "generisch" oder "agnostisch" ist.

Was wäre hier das richtige Wort und worin unterscheiden sie sich?

Comment: Praktischer Tipp: Warum schreibst du dann nicht einfach "der Software-Kern ist für unterschiedliche Anwendungsfälle immer derselbe"? Vielleicht ist auch den Lesern deines Textes der Unterschied zwischen bzw. sogar die genaue Bedeutung von agnostisch und generisch nicht klar.

Comment: @idmean Weil Fachsprache ihren Sinn und Zweck hat.

Comment: @infinitezero Ist das dann überhaupt eine Frage, die "German Language" betriftt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was jetzt folgt ist die Verwendung in der IT-Fachsprache; ich lasse andere Bereiche, in denen diese Begriffe benutzt werden, bewusst weg.

*Generisch* ist eine allgemeinere Aussage über eine Software oder Komponente als *agnostisch*.

**Agnostisch** bezieht sich im Allgemeinen auf einen speziellen Aspekt, gegenüber dem die Software agnostisch ist. Das Wort bedeutet "nicht wissend".
Wenn ich zum Beispiel alle Datenbank-Zugriffe einer Software in einer Komponente gekapselt habe, und alle anderen Komponenten nur darüber auf die DB zugreifen, dann sind alle anderen Komponenten agnostisch in Bezug auf die verwendete Datenbanksoftware. Sie wissen nichts darüber und müssen nichts darüber wissen. Man verwendet *agnostisch* eigentlich nie, ohne dass explizit oder implizit klar ist, auf welchen Aspekt es bezogen ist.

**Generisch** ist das Gegenteil von *spezifisch*. Synonyme sind   *universell* oder vielleicht *allgemein verwendbar*, aber mit *generisch* meint man eher universell durch Einfachheit, nicht dadurch, dass jeder denkbare Fall bedacht und abgehandelt wurde. Ein Hammer ist ein generisches Werkzeug, ein Schweizer Taschenmesser würde ich vielleicht als universell, aber eher nicht als generisch bezeichnen.

Man kann vielleicht auch sagen, eine generische Komponente ist eine, die in Bezug auf viele Aspekte agnostisch ist.

Excel ist ein generisches Tool zur Durchführung von Berechnungen verschiedenster Art. Es ist agnostisch in Bezug auf die Domäne, in der es eingesetzt wird, in Bezug auf die Daten, die damit verarbeitet werden, in Bezug auf die Zusammenhänge und Regeln, die für diese Daten gelten, in Bezug auf den Drucker, auf dem es druckt, etc.

Ein ORM-Mapper ist ein generisches Tool zur Abbildung von Objekten auf relationale Datenbanken und umgekehrt. Es ist u.a. agnostisch in Bezug auf die Geschäftslogik der Anwendung. Es ist sogar agnostisch gegenüber den konkreten Klassen und Tabellen der Anwedung, in der es eingesetzt wird -- der Entwickler des ORM-Mappers kannte diese Daten nicht und muss sie auch nicht kennen, um z.B. ein Update des ORM-Mappers zu schreiben.

Die Lagerverwaltung von IKEA ist, wenn sie speziell für IKEA entwickelt wurde, vermutlich das Gegenteil von generisch, sie ist spezialisiert und optimiert auf die Geschäftsprozesse, Daten, Geschäftsregeln von IKEA. Sie ist aber vielleicht in JAVA geschrieben und agnostisch in Bezug auf die genaue Hardware, auf der sie läuft.

In Bezug auf deine Kernkomponente könntest du also sagen, dass sie generisch ist, oder etwas präziser, dass sie gegenüber dem  "Anwendungsfall" agnostisch ist, wobei ich vermute, dass sich für "Anwendungsfall" im konkreten Fall auch noch ein präziseres Wort finden lässt.

Comment: Und nicht zu vergessen, dass manche Entwickler-Gemeinschaften (im speziellen Java und C#) das Wort "generisch" speziell für "parametrischen Polymorphismus" verwenden.

Answer (score 2):

Als Softwareentwickler würde ich in diesem Fall "generisch" nehmen in der Bedeutung "in allgemeingültigem Sinne".

"Agnostisch" ist meines Erachtens hier ein Anglizismus und hat im Deutschen nur eine religiöse Bedeutung ("Seine Weltanschauung ist agnostisch."). In diesem Kontext kenne ich es außerdem nur als zusammengesetztes Adjektiv auf Englisch, z.B. "platform agnostic" - was dann häufig wörtlich übersetzt wird zu "plattformagnostisch".

Comment: "Agnostisch" kommt aus dem Griechischen ;-)

Comment: Ja, natürlich. Dennoch ist die Verwendung von "-agnostisch" im IT-Bereich eine 1:1-Übersetzung aus dem Englischen und somit ein Anglizismus. "Sinn" ist ein deutsches Wort, dennoch ist "Sinn machen" ein Anglizismus. Bist du damit fein? ;-)